# Query string parameters duplicated every PJAX form update - 414 Request-URI Too Large

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2, pjax

**This is the ActiveForm with PJAX code in my view**:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false, 'id' => 'pjax-container']); ?>
...
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['method' => 'POST',], ['options' => ['data-pjax' => true]]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'form_input_1')->dropDownList($items, $params)->label(false); ?>
...
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
...
<?php echo ListView::widget([...]); ?>
...
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

**And i update it by js**:

```
$(document).on('change', 'filter dropdown_list', function(e) {
    $.pjax({
        push: false,
        timeout: 1000,
        url: $('#filter-form').attr('action'),
        container: '#pjax-conteiner',
        data: $('#filter-form').serializeArray(),
    });
});
```

So, every new query, the string parameters duplicated.

**Query String Parameters After first query**:

**_csrf**:VXswIzZsAyI2aQ==

**FormName[form_input_1]**:1

**FormName[form_input_1]**:2

**FormName[form_input_1]**:3

**_pjax**:#pjax-container

**Query String Parameters After second query:**

**_csrf**:VXswIzZsAyI2aQ==

**FormName[form_input_1]**:1

**FormName[form_input_1]**:2

**FormName[form_input_1]**:3

**_pjax**:#pjax-container

**_csrf**:VXswIzZsAyI2zZs==

**FormName[form_input_1]**:2

**FormName[form_input_1]**:3

**FormName[form_input_1]**:4

**_pjax**:#pjax-container

And after, for example, 15 queries, i have this error: **414 Request-URI Too Large**

Whats wrong and how can i fix it?

Comment: So, what is your question here? How to stop that, what to change..?

Comment: Yes, i think the Query String Parameters must resets every query.

Comment: And when i use "GET" form method the request url after 2 queries is: http://domain.com/controller/action? **_csrf** :VXswIzZsAyI2aQ==& **FormName[form_input_1]** =1& **FormName[form_input_2]** =2& **_csrf** :VXswIzZsA7654==& **FormName[form_input_1]** =3& **FormName[form_input_2]** =4

Comment: Hmm... I'm afraid I cannot answer this one, although I'm using Yii2 for quite a while now. :/

Comment: Don`t you saw this error when used pjax with form?

Comment: Well, my pjax queries did not duplicate, so no, I didn't see these errors. But I'll try tomorrow something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered same problem, so I made url clean method, which removes all duplicate params, leaving last one, which is default PHP behavior. Also, it works with array params, such as `Booking[status][]=1&Booking[status][]=4`.

```
function removeDuplicateUrlParams(url) {
            var params = new URLSearchParams(url);
            var result = {},
                isArrayKey,
                arrayKey,
                prevArrayKey = '';

            for (var p of params.entries()) {
                isArrayKey = p[0].indexOf('[]', p[0].length - 2) !== -1;
                if (isArrayKey) {
                    arrayKey = p[0].substr(0, p[0].length - 2);
                    if (arrayKey === prevArrayKey) {
                        result[arrayKey].push(p[1]);
                    } else {
                        result[arrayKey] = [p[1]];
                    }
                    prevArrayKey = arrayKey;
                } else {
                    result[p[0]] = p[1];
                    prevArrayKey = '';
                }
            }

            return $.param(result);
        }

var search = removeDuplicateUrlParams(window.location.search);
var url = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + '?' + search;

$.pjax.reload({
    container:'#pjax-container-id',
    url: url, 
    timeout: 10000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'replace' param set to false to avoid this.

> $.pjax.reload({
>     container: "#my-pjax-div", 
>     replace: false
>   });

See documentation [here](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)

Answer (score 0):

It seams the problem is comming from activeForm.
I solved that problem by defining an action for your form, like:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['method' => 'POST',], #<- are you sure, this is correct?
                               ['options' => ['data-pjax' => true]
                                'action' => Url::toRoute(['site/controller'])]
); ?>
```

Here you can find the reason an the how  to solve it: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/668/form-with-get-method-causes-repeated-stacking-of-url-parameters